# If $A$ is a $4 \times 6$ matrix with rank $3$, then the reduced row echelon form of $A$ has:

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Question. If $A$ is a $4 \times 6$ matrix with rank $3$, then the reduced row echelon form of
A has

(1) at least one zero row.
(2) at least one zero column.
(3) exactly two zero columns.
(4) at most three zero columns.

Since the rank is $3$, one row vector would be dependent, hence that would make up the row with zeroes, so (1) is correct.
I am a bit confused as to how to relate rank of a matrix with its columns. 
I think the answer should be (4) at most three zero columns since the rank = $3$ and the number of columns in a 4x6 matrix are 6.
Any insight?

Comment: Row Rank= Column Rank

Comment: then that would mean 3 column vectors are independent, thus the other 3 are dependent, so they could be made to be zero columns hence why (4) would be correct?

Comment: Compare: $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1&1&1\\0&1&0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ with $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.  Both have rank $3$, both are in RREF.

Comment: hypothetically speaking, if we had 5 rows and the rank was still 3, would that mean that we would have 2 rows consisting of zeroes?

Comment: After row reducing, yes.  Before row reducing, not necessarily.

Comment: As an aside, you say "total rows = 6."  Always say it in the order "rows" and "columns."  You will never hear me say the word rows after the word columns.  It is Rob and Charles, it is Robbers and Cops, Rumrunners and Coastguard, etc...  If $A$ is a $4\times 6$ matrix, then $A$ has *four* rows and *six* columns.

Comment: and since there is no rule for the columns, the columns could or could not be made into zero vectors

Comment: As for final result for the problem, (1) is true (*but could be improved to say* "**exactly** *one zero row*") and (4) is also true (*as there are some unknown number of zero columns between $0$ and $3$*).  The others are both false (*as shown by my examples in my first comment, we could have not had any columns made entirely of zeroes*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the martix is in its row reduced echelon form ,since the row rank and column rank are equal you have  one $0$ row and at most three $0$ columns. Thus the options $(1)$ and $(4)$ are correct.